# Shiny: how to create a confirm dialog box

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to ask if it is possible to have a confirm dialog box, consisting of two buttons, in shiny.
Say, if I click a Delete button, then the dialog box pop up. User pick the choice and return. The app acts according to the user choice.

Comment: [ShinyBS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyBS/shinyBS.pdf) might be worth a look?

Comment: I cannot make a window with 2 buttons. Do you know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified part of your code to call

```
js_string <- 'confirm("Are You Sure?");'
session$sendCustomMessage(type='jsCode', list(value = js_string))
```

to call the confirm dialog instead of alert dialog box. Then

```
tags$script(
            HTML('
                Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler(
                    type = "jsCode"
                    ,function(message) {
                    Shiny.onInputChange("deleteConfirmChoice",eval(message.value));
                })
            ')
)
```

to send the value returned by the confirm dialog box. Then I just checeked the value of input$deleteConfirmChoice to determine what action is to be done.
Thank you very much! I now understand how to send and receive messages to and from R and Javascript.

Answer (score 30):

Neither ShinyBS nor Javascript is necessary.  The trick is to use a `modalDialog` and set the footer to be a `tagList` of several tags, usually, an `actionButton` for the delete and a `modalButton` to cancel.  Below is a MWE

#### app.R

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
   mainPanel(
       actionButton("createfile", "Create"),
       actionButton("deletefile", "Delete")
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server = function(session, input, output) {

   observeEvent(input$createfile, {
       showModal(modalDialog(
           tagList(
               textInput("newfilename", label = "Filename", placeholder = "my_file.txt")
           ), 
           title="Create a file",
           footer = tagList(actionButton("confirmCreate", "Create"),
                            modalButton("Cancel")
           )
       ))
   })


   observeEvent(input$deletefile, {
       showModal(modalDialog(
           tagList(
               selectInput("deletefilename", label = "Delete a file", choices = list.files(pattern="*.txt"))
           ), 
           title="Delete a file",
           footer = tagList(actionButton("confirmDelete", "Delete"),
                            modalButton("Cancel")
           )
       ))
   })

   observeEvent(input$confirmCreate, {
       req(input$newfilename)
       file.create(input$newfilename)
       removeModal()
   })

   observeEvent(input$confirmDelete, {
       req(input$deletefilename)
       file.remove(input$deletefilename)
       removeModal()
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note, if you use shiny modules, you have to use `session$ns("inputID")` rather than `ns("inputID")`. See [Tobias' answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127459/using-modal-window-in-shiny-module).

Comment: This is the clearest and best answer here. It's also highly extensible.

Comment: Elegant and requiring no further libraries other than Shiny. I can confirm it works too.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

**Update** using `sweetalertR`

```
#install_github("timelyportfolio/sweetalertR")
library(shiny)
library(sweetalertR)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("go", "Go"),
    sweetalert(selector = "#go", text = "hello", title = "world")
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
))
```

[image]

**Example 1**

You can do something like this, note that the code is taken from [Demo on submit button with pop-up (IN PROGRESS)](https://gist.github.com/ptoche/8693347)

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui =basicPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(type='text/css', 
               "select, textarea, input[type='text'] {margin-bottom: 0px;}"
               , "#submit {
          color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
          text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
          background-color: rgb(189,54,47);
          background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(238,95,91), rgb(189,54,47));
          background-repeat: repeat-x;
          border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        }"
    ),
    tags$script(HTML('
          Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("jsCode",
            function(message) {
              eval(message.value);
            }
          );'
    ))
  )
  ,
  textInput(inputId = "inText", label = "", value = "Something here")
  ,
  actionButton(inputId = "submit", label = "Submit")
  #  
  #   alternative approach: button with pop-up
  #    , tags$button("Activate", id = "ButtonID", type = "button", class = "btn action-button", onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure?');" )
  ,
  tags$br()
  ,
  tags$hr()
  ,
  uiOutput("outText")
)
server = (
  function(session, input, output) {

    observe({
      if (is.null(input$submit) || input$submit == 0){return()}
      js_string <- 'alert("Are You Sure?");'
      session$sendCustomMessage(type='jsCode', list(value = js_string))
      text <- isolate(input$inText)
      output$outText <- renderUI({
        h4(text)
      })
    })

  }
)
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

**Example 2**

Using `ShinyBS` package

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

campaigns_list <- letters[1:10]

ui =fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("campaigns","Choose campaign(s):",campaigns_list),
  actionLink("selectall","Select All"),
  bsModal("modalExample", "Yes/No", "selectall", size = "small",wellPanel(
    actionButton("no_button", "Yes"),
    actionButton("yes_button", "No")
    ))
)
server = function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    if(input$selectall == 0) return(NULL) 
    else if (input$selectall%%2 == 0)
    {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"campaigns","Choose campaign(s):",choices=campaigns_list)      
    }
    else
    {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"campaigns","Choose campaign(s):",choices=campaigns_list,selected=campaigns_list)
    }
  })


}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

**Edit for Apricot**

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

campaigns_list <- letters[1:10]

ui =fluidPage(
        checkboxGroupInput("campaigns","Choose campaign(s):",campaigns_list),
        actionLink("selectall","Select All"),
        bsModal("modalExample", "Yes/No", "selectall", size = "small",wellPanel(
                actionButton("yes_button", "Yes"),
                actionButton("no_button", "No")
        ))
)
server = function(input, output, session) {

        observeEvent(input$no_button,{
                updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"campaigns","Choose campaign(s):",choices=campaigns_list) 
        })

        observeEvent(input$yes_button,{
                updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"campaigns","Choose campaign(s):",choices=campaigns_list,selected=campaigns_list)
        })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: @Porkchop Hi I was trying to use your second example using shiny BS. When I ran the example I realised the control of selection still lies with the "selectall" link and not the "yes" or "No" options of the bsModals. Is it possible to pass on the control to yes or no wherein even if selectall selects all the options, if I click No in the modal window it should reset the selection of the check boxes.