# Why do we use session$ns in Shiny modules and not NS(id)?

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

Consider any Shiny module in which we use `session$ns` in the server part, e.g. the one below.

We could equivalently use `NS(id)` instead of `session$ns`. So why it is recommended to use `session$ns`? Is there an advantage over `NS(id)`?

```r
library(shiny)

myModuleUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("checkbox"))
}

myModuleServer <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    output[["checkbox"]] <- renderUI({
      checkboxInput(ns("checkbox"), label = "Check me", value = FALSE)
    })
    observe({
      print(input[["checkbox"]])
    })
  })
}

ui <- basicPage(
  myModuleUI("myModule")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  myModuleServer("myModule")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: 'recommended to use session$ns' - please enlighten me.

Comment: Probably because it is mentioned in the official [shiny tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html), which e.g. I also used when I created a module tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why?

`session$ns` is mandatory if you want to use nested modules which use dynamic UI with `uiOutput`

#### Minimal example

```
library(shiny)
## NESTED MODULE
nestedModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("ui_out"))
}

nestedModuleServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      output$ui_out <- renderUI({
        list(
          actionButton(session$ns("well_formed"), "I work"),
          actionButton(NS(id, "bad_formed"), "I do nothin'")
        )
      })

      observeEvent(input$well_formed,  print("button pressed!"))
      observeEvent(input$bad_formed,  print("button pressed!"))
    }
  )
}

## CONTAINER MODULE
containerModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  nestedModuleUI(ns("nested"))
}

containerModuleServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      nestedModuleServer("nested")
    }
  )
}

## Application
ui <-  containerModuleUI("container")

server <- function(input, output, session) containerModuleServer("container")

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48127806/6537892)

Answer (score 4):

When I see it correctly, it's due to how the module API was structured before `shiny 1.5.0`. Until then, you had to write module `server` functions in the following way:

```
myModuleServer <- function(input, output, session){
  ns <- session$ns
  output[["checkbox"]] <- renderUI({
    checkboxInput(ns("checkbox"), label = "Check me", value = FALSE)
  })
  observe({
    print(input[["checkbox"]])
  })
}
```

and call a module with:

```
callModule(myModuleServer, id = "myModule")
```

With this API, you don't have an `id` variable for your module `server` function and you had to resort to `session$ns`. This is still (erroneously) mentioned in the ["Using renderUI within modules" part of the shiny tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).

> If your renderUI block itself contains inputs/outputs, you need to use ns() to wrap your ID arguments, just like in the examples above. But those ns instances were created using NS(id), and in this case, there’s no id parameter to use. What to do?
> The session parameter can provide the ns for you; just call ns <- session$ns. This will put the ID in the same namespace as the session.

The above is not true any more for the new API.

Indeed, in [Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-modules.html#dynamic-ui), they use `NS(id)` also in the `server` part of a module.

However, I'm not sure if there are any subtle differences between using `NS(id)` and `session$ns` in the module `server` with the new API (but considering "Mastering Shiny" uses it, I don't think so).

Comment: I think `session$ns` is more convenient when there are nested modules.

Comment: Downvoted because it is inaccurate, see my answer.